# angular2 testing framework async testing issue

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, angular, karma-jasmine

I have created angular 2 a project and a service with angular-cli and tried to test my service.

But API does not fail in async function although it should fail ;moreover, it just ignores those exceptions.

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

import {
  beforeEach, beforeEachProviders, describe, xdescribe,
  expect, it, xit, async, inject, injectAsync
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SearchService } from './search.service';
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from '@angular/http/testing';
import {XHRBackend, Response, ResponseOptions, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

describe('Search Service', () => {
  let searchService: SearchService;
  let mockBackend: MockBackend;

  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    MockBackend,
    provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: MockBackend }),
    SearchService
  ]);

  beforeEach(injectAsync([SearchService, MockBackend], (s, m) => {
    searchService = s;
    mockBackend = m;
  }));

  it('async test', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(2).toBe(1);
    }, 3000);
  });
```

It just ignores those minimal test case.

Then I have read some doc and updated my code as follow.

```
it('async test with done', (done) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(1).toBe(1);
    done();
  }, 1000);
});
```

But this time, the test fails although it should pass. The error is as follow.

**Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.**

I change default timeout value to bigger value but it is no effect.

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: its version is 2.0.0-rc.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`injectAsync` will not work, use `async` (stopped working for me after rc2)

[angular2 change log beta 16](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-200-beta16-2016-04-26)

injectAsync is now deprecated. Instead, use the async function to wrap any asynchronous tests.
You will also need to add the dependency 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js' as a served file in your Karma or other test configuration.

Before:

```
it('should wait for returned promises', injectAsync([FancyService], (service) => {
  return service.getAsyncValue().then((value) => { expect(value).toEqual('async value'); });
}));
it('should wait for returned promises', injectAsync([], () => {
  return somePromise.then(() => { expect(true).toEqual(true); });
}));
```

After:

```
it('should wait for returned promises', async(inject([FancyService], (service) => {
  service.getAsyncValue().then((value) => { expect(value).toEqual('async value'); });
})));
// Note that if there is no injection, we no longer need `inject` OR `injectAsync`.
it('should wait for returned promises', async(() => {
  somePromise.then(() => { expect(true).toEqual(true); });
}));
```

Comment: Can you update answer by the update of the question?